# C# Parsing an XML and storing it into a Class

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmlnode

I need to parse an XML and store it into a class but it's been giving me a lot more headaches than I'm happy to admit.

Assume the XML looks like this:

```
<PARENT>
    <ITEM>
        <DATA1>
            <A>12345</A>
            <B>12345</B>
            <C>12345</C>
        </DATA1>
        <DATA2>
            <D>12345</D>
            <E>12345</E>
            <F>12345</F>
        </DATA2>
        <DATA3>
            <ITEM>
                <G/>
                <H>111</H>
                <I>223</I>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                <G/>
                <H>2342</H>
                <I>25323</I>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                <G>185</G>
                <H>63611</H>
                <I/>
            </ITEM>
        </DATA3>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <DATA1>
            <A>23456</A>
            <B>23456</B>
            <C>23456</C>
        </DATA1>
    </ITEM>
</PARENT>
```

The first problem I'm facing is the fact that the name "**ITEM**" doesn't only appear as a childnode of "**PARENT**" but is also reused again under of "**DATA3**" so if I just search like this

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(tmp);
IEnumerable<XElement> tmp_list = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("ITEM"));
```

it will give me gives me five results instead of just two.

I've also already tried the approach of searching the path //PARENT/ITEM like this:

```
string file = @"C:\temp\test.xml";

var document = XDocument.Load(file);
var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("empty", "random:namespace:name");

IEnumerable<XElement> ele_list = document.XPathSelectElements("//PARENT//ITEM", namespaceManager);
```

but it doesn't work either since it also fetches the all the grandchild nodes...

**Question 1)** How can I correctly restrict the search to just the top level nodes?

**Question 2)** How would I then proceed and store the whole thing into a class in the most efficient way? I've tried copypasting the full XML response to websites like http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ but all of them seem to be struggling with the duplicate name "**ITEM**" and basically create one class that has merged ALL of the different "**ITEM**" child nodes within. Is it possible to fill a List of items in a simple and efficient way? I was hoping to have essentially something along the lines of:

```
List<DataItem> grd_list = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("ITEM"))
   .Select(f => new DataItem()
   {
      DATA1 = f.Element(XName.Get("DATA1")).Document.ToString(),
      DATA2 = f.Element(XName.Get("DATA2")).Document.ToString(),
      //etc.....
   }).ToList();
```

but I'm aware that the above LINQ would have to be more complex than this since DATA1 etc also needs to have child nodes.

Comment: When using XDocument, you can use the .Element("Name") property instead of .Descendants("...") to just get direct child elements of a node

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. Using this this seems to work of giving me just the two "ITEM" nodes on the top level. Thanks. Now I'll need to tackle the 2nd question :-)

```XElement main = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("PARENT")).First(); IEnumerable<XElement> tmp_list = main.Elements("ITEM");```

Comment: Worth noting there's an implicit conversion from `string` to `XName`. You don't need to use `XName.Get` - `doc.Descendants("PARENT")` is enough.

Comment: @CharlesMager: Right, good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use serializer XML  (its just an example following your xml)

you could avoid the problem of item by defining all cases in the definition of the class ITEM. So the items not presents (G,H,I or DATA1,DATA2.. will be null).

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PARENT));
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
   var test = (PARENT)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
  :
  :
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "DATA1")]
public class DATA1
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "A")]
    public string A { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "B")]
    public string B { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "C")]
    public string C { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "DATA2")]
public class DATA2
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "D")]
    public string D { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "E")]
    public string E { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "F")]
    public string F { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ITEM")]
public class ITEM
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "G")]
    public string G { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "H")]
    public string H { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "I")]
    public string I { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DATA1")]
    public DATA1 DATA1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DATA2")]
    public DATA2 DATA2 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DATA3")]
    public DATA3 DATA3 { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "DATA3")]
public class DATA3
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ITEM")]
    public List<ITEM> ITEM { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PARENT")]
public class PARENT
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ITEM")]
    public List<ITEM> ITEM { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot for your answer! - you had me scared there for a moment when it was deleted ;) Your generated example class of ITEM is similar to what I outlined in my OP regarding generators like XmlToCSharp will do: Generate an ITEM Class that not only contains DATA1, DATA2 and DATA3 but also G, H and I due to the "ITEM" Child nested within DATA3.

Is there no way of having these separated?

Having a bunch of null values is not an issue per se (I can work around that) but it'd be cleaner if those could be separated somehow :-) Thanks again!

Comment: no you cant separate it, because the xml serializater will not be functional..you just play with it ..but if you want to search something with linq its very easy

Comment: Ah okay. How would you for example search for the Data3-Items with linq then? Do you need to "hardcode" the path like //PARENT//ITEM/DATA3//ITEM or what would be the best way to do that? I've already translate your example code to my much more complex real world example...it's working like a charm. Thank you again so so much!

Comment: you do var search = test.ITEM.Select(x => x.DATA3);   and so you could iterate with foreach thru all ITEM